# Is it possible to use Silverlight Toolkit themes in Windows Phone 7 applications?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is that possible to use [themes](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home) from Silverlight Toolkit in Windows Phone 7 applications?
Or they are only for desktop/web applications and not included in toolkit for WP7?

Is there any tricks that could let me use them in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
I figure it out by myself.
All you need to do to use original Silverlight Toolkit themes is to

1. Get its sources
2. Take out themes xaml files from them
3. Place this needed theme as a style for desired control in your WP7 app resouces
4. Apply new style to desired control.

Answer (score 2):

Theming support is not built into the toolkit for WP7.

The controls in the Phone version of the Toolkit support the configurable themes on the phone. (i.e. Dark/light themes and accent colours.)

If you wanted to do this and had re-templated all the other controls you were using, it shouldn't be that much more work to apply your custom styles to the toolkit controls too.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 has adopted a style of theming refered to as Metro. You can get some background on this if you watch [CL14 from Mix10](http://Albert).

The resources you can use are covered here.

[Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

You aren't obliged to follow this theming however and can integrate other styles if you choose to.